# lexically set referenced symbol of a symbol within let bind form

Tags: let-binding

Is it possible to set a symbol that is the value of target symbol within the let bind form? because I am not setting a target symbol, I am not sure how to use let.

I am doing this because I am passing in a string that represents a library's name to generate a function for the library.
look at the following link to see how I am using it
https://github.com/natask/sexp-string/blob/6b748c133da51a129a465a426ae43b06c3a1331d/sexp-string.el#L189.

starting point,
The following is a valid let form

```el
(setq boolean 'dynamic-value)
(print boolean) ;; prints 'dynamic-value
(let ((boolean 'lexical-value))
   (print boolean)) ;; prints 'lexical-value
```

I am looking to modify lexically the variable boolean from a variable boolean-variable that contains the symbol boolean. boolean-variable is like a pointer to the pointer boolean.

```el
(setq boolean 'first-value)
(setq boolean-variable 'boolean)
(print (symbol-value boolean-variable)) ;; prints 'first-value
(set  boolean-variable 'second-value)
(print boolean) ;; prints 'second-value
```

what I have,

```el
(setq boolean 'dynamic-value)
(setq boolean-variable (intern-soft "boolean"))
(print boolean-variable) ;; prints 'boolean
(print (symbol-value boolean-variable)) ;; prints 'dynamic-value
(let ((old-boolean-variable (symbol-value boolean-variable)))
          (set boolean-variable 'lexical-value)
          ;; use boolean-variable in a function
          (print (symbol-value boolean-variable)) ;; prints 'lexical-value
          ;; set the value of variable back to previous value
          (set boolean-variable old-boolean-variable))
(print (symbol-value boolean-variable))  ;; prints 'dynamic-value
```

what I am looking for ,

```el
(setq boolean 'dynamic-value)
(setq boolean-variable (intern-soft "boolean"))
(print boolean-variable) ;; prints 'boolean
(print (symbol-value boolean-variable)) ;; prints 'dynamic-value
(let (((symbol-content boolean-variable) 'lexical-value))) ;; creates a lexical binding to symbol 'boolean
    (print (access-symbol-lexically boolean-variable)) ;; prints 'lexical-value
)
(print (symbol-value boolean-variable)) ;; prints 'dynamic-value
```

I am not using the variable boolean directly but through a symbol because I am passing in a string
something like the following.

```el
(setq boolean-1 'dynamic-value)
(setq boolean-2 'dynamic-value)
(defun my-fun (library)
(setq boolean-variable1 (intern-soft (concat library "-1")))
(setq boolean-variable2 (intern-soft (concat library "-2")))
;;utilize variables
)
(my-fun "boolean")
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: (1) The question isn't clear to me at all - but that might just be me. I have no idea what you're trying to do or asking. (2) `symbol-value` is explicitly for dynamically scoped variables. See `C-h f symbol-value` and (elisp) [Accessing Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Accessing-Variables.html).

Comment: Your example `let` form is strange/confusing.  The whole "save the current value, do a thing, restore the original value" process is robustly taken care of by `let` -- you don't need to manually save and restore the value; it will be restored once the let-binding ends.  Following `(let ((foo newvalue)) do-a-thing)` the symbol `foo` will have its original value again.

Comment: @drew, I have added more context. In short, lexically utilize a variable behind a variable as supposed to lexically utilizing a variable.

Comment: I don't see any edit with additional context. The question is still not clear to me.

Comment: My apologies. my edit had not gone through. It now has.

Comment: I have a hunch that the tool you're looking for is `gensym`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@phils comment on his answer lead me to think of the following.

```el
(setq boolean 'dynamic-value)
(setq boolean-variable (intern-soft "boolean"))
(print boolean-variable) ;; prints 'boolean
(print (symbol-value boolean-variable)) ;; prints 'dynamic-value
(eval `(let ((,boolean-variable 'lexical-value)) ;; creates a lexical binding
    (print ,boolean-variable) ;; prints 'lexical-value
    (print boolean) ;;prints 'lexical-value
))
(print (symbol-value boolean-variable)) ;; prints 'dynamic-value
```

strangely, I had to pass environment variables to eval in my case. I had thought eval captures environment variables automatically.
https://github.com/natask/sexp-string/blob/9fbacdf620d9077b60270c63eaa6267be75fd855/sexp-string.el#L200

```el
                    (eval
                     `(let ((,boolean-variable (or boolean ,boolean-variable)))
                     (pcase parsed-sexp
                        (`(,_) (->> `,(backquote ,(car parsed-sexp))
                                    backquote
                                    eval
                                    sexp-string-collapse-list))
                        (_ nil))) (list (cons 'boolean boolean) (cons 'parsed-sexp parsed-sexp))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, if you have `lexical-binding` enabled in your library, then it cannot treat a given name as both dynamic and lexical.  If you have declared a variable as dynamic by using `defvar`, then it will not be treated as lexically-bound.  You must pick one or the other.  This shouldn't be a problem because, by definition, *all* of the code which can access a lexically-bound variable is right there in that same block of code (within the scope of the lexical binding), where you can edit it -- so there's absolutely no reason to be using the same name as a dynamic variable.

Alternatively (but again, I don't see why you might need this) you can utilise the fake lexical binding macro `lexical-let` from the `cl` library, which was typically used to imitate lexical binding back when Emacs only supported dynamic binding.

---

> I am looking to modify lexically the variable `boolean` from a variable `boolean-variable` that contains the symbol `boolean`. `boolean-variable` is like a pointer to the pointer `boolean`.

No, if you are using `lexical-binding` then this is not possible at all.  There's no way of taking a symbol name and using it to find a lexical variable of that name, because the lexical variable isn't associated with the symbol at all.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Lexical Binding` explains:

> Note that unlike dynamic variables which are tied to the symbol
> object itself, the relationship between lexical variables and symbols is
> only present in the interpreter (or compiler).  Therefore, functions
> which take a symbol argument (like ‘symbol-value’, ‘boundp’, and ‘set’)
> can only retrieve or modify a variable’s dynamic binding (i.e., the
> contents of its symbol’s value cell).

Within the scope of a lexical-binding the only code which can access a given lexical variable is the code which directly references the variable name.

Comment: do you think there is a better way to use variables of a symbol as symbols themselves than creating a backup and reverting as above?

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you're doing, but one option would be to write a lisp macro which generates `let` bindings for the *actual* variable names (i.e. the ones generated from the strings) and evaluates the body code within that.

Comment: Hi @phils , do you have any comments on my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting with `defmacro` I think I found a way of taking a symbol name and using it to find the lexical value of the variable by that name under lexical-binding.

This makes a somewhat unconventional use of `defmacro` and I cannot say that I fully understand what is going on but I think this might contradict phils's statement in his answer above according to which:

> No, if you are using lexical-binding then this is not possible at all.
> There's no way of taking a symbol name and using it to find a lexical
> variable of that name, because the lexical variable isn't associated
> with the symbol at all.

```
 ;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

 (defmacro access-symbol-lexically (symbol)
   (eval symbol))

 (setq my-var "Dynamical")

 (let ((my-var "Lexical"))
   (print (access-symbol-lexically (intern "my-var")))  ;; prints "Lexical"
   )
```

The example discussed by the OP is mostly related to *accessing*
a lexical variable but the question itself also mentions
*setting* such variables.  Here is a similar trick that does it:

```
 ;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

 (defmacro set-symbol-lexically (symbol val)
   `(setq ,(eval symbol) ,val))

 (setq my-var "Dynamical")

 (let (my-var)
   (set-symbol-lexically (intern "my-var") "Lexical")
   (print my-var)  ;; prints "Lexical"
   )
```

Applying this to the question posed by the OP, we have:

```
 ;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

 (defmacro access-symbol-lexically (symbol)
   (eval symbol))


 (setq boolean 'dynamic-value)
 (setq boolean-variable (intern-soft "boolean"))
 (print boolean-variable) ;; prints 'boolean
 (print (symbol-value boolean-variable)) ;; prints 'dynamic-value

 (let ((boolean 'lexical-value)) ;; creates a lexical binding to symbol 'boolean
 (print (access-symbol-lexically boolean-variable)) ;; prints 'lexical-value
 )
 (print (symbol-value boolean-variable)) ;; prints 'dynamic-value
```

---

EDIT: Here are some further examples of the above `defmacro` trick.

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(defmacro access-symbol-lexically (symbol)
  (eval symbol))

(setq my-var "Dynamical")

(let ((my-var "Lexical"))
  (print (access-symbol-lexically (intern "my-var"))) ;; Prints "Lexical" (same as above example)
  (print (access-symbol-lexically 'my-var)) ;; Prints "Lexical"
  (setq s 'my-var)
  (print (access-symbol-lexically s)) ;; Prints "Lexical"
  (let ((s 'my-var) (my-var "Doubly Lexical")) (print (access-symbol-lexically s))) ;; Prints "Doubly Lexical"
  (let ((s 'my-var) ) (print (access-symbol-lexically s))) ;; Prints "Lexical"
  ;; From now on commands do not use above defmacro trick
  (print (eval 'my-var)) ;; Prints "Dynamical"
  (print (eval s)) ;; Prints "Dynamical"
  )
```

Comment: For sure, macro expansion happens before evaluation, and `(let ((my-var "Lexical")) (print (access-symbol-lexically (intern "my-var"))))` expands to `(let ((my-var "Lexical")) (print my-var))`.  Remember that macro expansion happens "at some unknown point in the past" compared to evaluation time, so any macro code/usage needs to be doing the right thing at expansion time for its evaluation at some unknown point in the future.